# Select SQL results grouped by weeks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to select data from following table group by weeks

```
 Date       Product Name   Sale
+----------+--------------+-----+
 14-05-11     a             2
 14-05-11     b             4 
 17-05-11     c             3
 19-05-11     a             6
 24-05-11     a             6
 29-05-11     a             6
```

Let suppose today is `30-05-11`

So my result should look like this.

```
 Product Name         First Week   Second Week  Third Week
+--------------------+------------+------------+-------------+
   a                      12            6           2
   b                       0            0           4 
   c                       0            3           0
```

Will some body guide me to how to write SQL query to achieve this behavior!

Comment: Another way to group by weeks is to use `GROUP BY DATEPART(ww,rREPORT_DATE)`. You could also include the week start or end date with an aggregate like `MIN(REPORT_DATE)`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think this should do it..

```
Select 
ProductName,
WeekNumber,
sum(sale)
from
(
    SELECT 
    ProductName,
    DATEDIFF(week, '2011-05-30', date) AS WeekNumber,
    sale
    FROM table
)
GROUP BY
ProductName,
WeekNumber
```

Comment: i want to show weeks as column,s(1st week  second week and so on)

Comment: Are there a set number of weeks you want to display? If not then this is pretty difficult, as you need to explicitly specify the column headings to pivot the data..

Comment: I want to display upto 15 weeks!

Comment: If its set to 15 weeks, then just pivot these results, defining 15 columns

Comment: @StevieG uaing same method I am trying to Join Two tables and execute same query. Have a look at this

Select CP.ProductName,MonthNumber,sum(Cp.ProductQuantity ) as QTY
from(
 SELECT CP.ProductName, DATEDIFF(month, '2015-01-01','2015-12-31') AS MonthNumber,
    Cp.ProductQuantity
      FROM VendorTrading VT inner join CustomerProducts CP on VT.Id = Cp.VendorTradingId
   WHERE (VT.Tradedate between isnull(NULL,VT.Tradedate) and isnull(NULL,VT.Tradedate))
   )
GROUP BY
CP.ProductName,
MonthNumber

But It is giving error on GROUP BY Function (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.)

Comment: your where clause doesn't make much sense?

Comment: This did not work for me, I get a syntax error at GROUP BY too. I got rid of  subquery and replaced DATEDIFF with DATEPART(wk,date) and grouped by the same. This is much simpler and works fine. I'm upvoting this answer however, because it pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: This also didn't work for me until i named the subclause as something after the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 27):

the provided solutions seem a little complex? this might help:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

```
select
   mystuff,
   DATEPART ( year, MyDateColumn ) as yearnr,
   DATEPART ( week, MyDateColumn ) as weeknr
from mytable
group by ...etc
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @increddibelly `DatePart()` doesn't calculate more than 53 weeks in group by  
 `SELECT PCalcBirdsProduction.Birds,isnull(sum(Mortality),0)[Mortality],isnull(sum(Feed),0)[Feed],isnull(Sum(Eggs),0)[Eggs], 
isnull(Sum(Hatchable),0)[Hatchable],isnull(sum(Produced),0)[Produced],isnull(SUM(Broiler),0)[Broiler],
isnull(sum(Exportable),0)[Exportable]
FROM PCalcBirdsMain inner join PCalcBirdsProduction on PCalcBirdsMain.Id = PCalcBirdsProduction.PCalcBirdsMainId  
WHERE PCalcBirdsProduction.Dated between '2020/11/01' and '2022/12/28' And 
group by DATEPART(ww, Dated)` How to fix this ?

Comment: late to the party, but try iso_week see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#iso_week-datepart

Answer (score 15):

This should do it for you:

```
Declare @DatePeriod datetime

Set @DatePeriod = '2011-05-30'

Select  ProductName,
        IsNull([1],0) as 'Week 1',
        IsNull([2],0) as 'Week 2',
        IsNull([3],0) as 'Week 3',
        IsNull([4],0) as 'Week 4',
        IsNull([5], 0) as 'Week 5'

From 
(
Select  ProductName,
        DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, InputDate), 0), InputDate) +1 as [Weeks],
        Sale as 'Sale'

From dbo.YourTable
-- Only get rows where the date is the same as the DatePeriod
-- i.e DatePeriod is 30th May 2011 then only the weeks of May will be calculated
Where DatePart(Month, InputDate)= DatePart(Month, @DatePeriod)
)p 
Pivot (Sum(Sale) for Weeks in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) as pv
```

It will calculate the week number relative to the month. So instead of week 20 for the year it will be week 2. The `@DatePeriod` variable is used to fetch only rows relative to the month (in this example only for the month of May)

**Output using my sample data:**

[image]

Comment: add DatePart(YEAR, InputDate)= DatePart(YEAR, @DatePeriod) in where condition or else if the table has 4 years data then all the data of the month 'MAY' will sum up.

Comment: Please add 6th Week also. A month can have upto 6weeks like April 2017

Answer (score 2):

Base on @increddibelly answer, I applied to my query as below.

I share for whom concerned.

My table structure `FamilyData(Id, nodeTime, totalEnergy)`

```
select
   sum(totalEnergy) as TotalEnergy,
   DATEPART ( week, nodeTime ) as weeknr
from FamilyData
group by DATEPART (week, nodeTime)
```

Comment: Will this work if ```DATEPART (week, nodeTime)``` wasn't in the `SELECT` clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @DatePeriod datetime
Set @DatePeriod = '2011-05-30'

Select  ProductName,
        IsNull([1],0) as 'Week 1',
        IsNull([2],0) as 'Week 2',
        IsNull([3],0) as 'Week 3',
        IsNull([4],0) as 'Week 4',
        IsNull([5], 0) as 'Week 5'
From 
(
Select  ProductName,
        DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '2011-05-30'), 0), '2011-05-30') +1 as [Weeks],
        Sale as 'Sale'
From dbo.WeekReport

-- Only get rows where the date is the same as the DatePeriod
-- i.e DatePeriod is 30th May 2011 then only the weeks of May will be calculated
Where DatePart(Month, '2011-05-30')= DatePart(Month, @DatePeriod)
)p 
Pivot (Sum(Sale) for Weeks in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) as pv
```

OUTPUT LOOK LIKE THIS

```
a   0   0   0   0   20
b   0   0   0   0   4
c   0   0   0   0   3
```