# How to get the count (item) for week in year using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is a little bit hard to explain what I need to do but I will try my best and please help me. The real work is much more complicated, however, I need know how to do the basic first.

Assume I have a table called `TABLE-A` which `ID` is primary key, `TYPE`, And `Approved Date` the `YEAR('Approved Date')` has actually range of several years. I would like to have a `SELECT STATEMENT` of which it runs the `COUNT(TYPE)` for every week in a specified year (In this case `WHERE YEAR = 2011`. How could I solve this problem?

In my company, currently, we use an Excel file which just downloaded the whole table and do a lot of calculations with large number of extra columns just to get this result.

[image]

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410134/how-to-select-sql-results-group-by-weeks) is close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks - it is possible to automatically create Week 1 to Week 52 in a year rather than create manually 52 weeks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL and `PIVOT` to achieve your goal

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME('week ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(isowk, adate)) 
                                                   + ' - ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), YEAR(adate)))
            FROM Table1
            ORDER BY 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @sql = 'SELECT type, ' + @cols +   
           '  FROM 
            (
              SELECT type, 
                     ''week '' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(isowk, adate)) 
                               + '' - '' 
                               + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), YEAR(adate)) week, 
                     COUNT(*) type_count
                FROM table1
               WHERE adate BETWEEN ''20130101'' AND ''20131231''
               GROUP BY type, YEAR(adate), DATEPART(isowk, adate)
            ) x
            PIVOT 
            (
               MAX(type_count) FOR week IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY type'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Sample output:

```
| TYPE | WEEK 1 - 2013 | WEEK 2 - 2013 |
----------------------------------------
|    A |             4 |             1 |
|    B |             2 |             2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef376/1)** demo

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks very complicated :( but I will try