# check if date is within a date range

Tags: php, sql

I have a database filled with a bunch of jobs, where I have startDate and endDate.
What Im trying to do is to list current week and 20 weeks ahead, and see if those weeks are within the database. 
And when I echo it out I want the date to be green if the date exists and black if not.

It works, but the problem is that it skips the first week. So if I have 2014-07-01 as startDate and 2014-07-14 as endDate, then the second week in that example will get green, not the first one.

This is what I'v done:

**UPDATED**

```
$last = 19;
$today = new \DateTime();
$today->modify('Monday this week');

for ($i=0; $i<$last; $i++) {
  $the_week = $today->format('o-m-d');

  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT startDate,endDate FROM work WHERE '$the_week' BETWEEN startDate AND endDate'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  $startdate = $row['startDate'];
  $enddate = $row['endDate'];

if(($startdate > $the_week) AND ($enddate < $the_week)) { 
 $color = "#69dd54;"; } else { $color = "#ffffff;"; }

    echo "<span style='color: ". $color ."'>". $the_week ."</span>";
    $new_today->modify('next Monday');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the output of your foreach loop for $the_week

```
2014-07-09
2014-07-16
2014-07-23
2014-07-30
2014-08-06
2014-08-13
2014-08-20
2014-08-27
2014-09-03
2014-09-10
2014-09-17
2014-09-24
2014-10-01
2014-10-08
2014-10-15
2014-10-22
2014-10-29
2014-11-05
2014-11-12
2014-11-19
```

as you can see the second one is outside of your date range

Try this as your loop

```
    //$first = 0;
    $last = 19;
    //$weeks = range($first, $last);
    $today = new \DateTime();
    $today->modify('Monday this week');

    for ($i=0; $i<$last; $i++) {        
        $the_week = $today->format('o-m-d');
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT startDate,endDate FROM work WHERE $the_week BETWEEN startData AND endDate"); //what happend to your original query.
        $r = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

        $startdate = $row['startDate'];
        $enddate = $row['endDate'];

       if(($startdate > $the_week) AND ($enddate < $the_week)) { 
           $color = "#69dd54;"; } else { $color = "#ffffff;";
       }

    echo "<span style='color: ". $color ."'>". $the_week ."</span>";
        $today->modify('next Monday');
    }
```

outputs

```
2014-07-07
2014-07-14
2014-07-21
2014-07-28
2014-08-04
2014-08-11
2014-08-18
2014-08-25
2014-09-01
2014-09-08
2014-09-15
2014-09-22
2014-09-29
2014-10-06
2014-10-13
2014-10-20
2014-10-27
2014-11-03
2014-11-10
```

Using DateTime you can increment by the 'next Monday' or any day for that matter, with a simple for loop.

also make sure to change

```
$startdate = $ro['startDate'];
  $enddate = $ro['endDate'];
```

to

```
$startdate = $row['startDate'];
  $enddate = $row['endDate'];
```

Comment: I changed it now, I removed the between statement, and tried to get it done with a if statement, but I still can not get it right.

Comment: Also looking again I think my dev server is in Germany time lol, it's a day behind.

Comment: All this query is doing is getting the first row every time.

Comment: before or after it got messed up, it currently is not like it originally was, it was yada yada FROM work WHERE $start_week BETWEEN yada, yada.

Comment: Each edit serves to create a new problem without ever having fixed the original one.

Comment: I saw that I had done the between all wrong. Is there a way to check a date between two columns?

Comment: I tried to skip the between thing, and did a greater/small than, but the problem is the same, so the problem is the dates, think I have to rewrite this so that the dates are correct. Although I dont see why it should not already.

Comment: I tried DateTime instead. But the problem still stands, the first week still skips. I will update what I got now.

Answer (score 0):

What is `$the_week`?  It appears to be a date, but there are many dates in a week.  For example there is the first date of a week and the last date of the week.  It could be that you have a problematic boundary condition here.

You want the **start date** to be **before** the **last day** of a week, and the **end date** to be **after** the **first day** of a week, I am assuming.  Therefore the first week gets excluded because its first day is before the start date, and yet its last day is after the start date.

**UPDATE:**

Consider having:

```
$the_week = date('o-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + '. $week .' week'));
$the_week_last = date('o-m-d', strtotime($today. ($week +1) .' week'));
```

By the way, I would recommend you do a single SQL query for this, rather than one for every week.  There is an example of how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410134/how-to-select-sql-results-group-by-weeks).

Comment: $the_week is current week + $week, so it all counts from todays date.

Comment: The same logic applies here.  There are always two dates to be concerned with: the first date of a week and the last date of a week.