# How do you create dates in SQL without typing them all out and then create an aggregation for trailing weeks?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

A question I have is how do you create a temporary table of dates without typing all of them out row after row of cases.

For example, today is the 18 November 2018. How would I create a table or use today's date as a query for my tables. So the 18 November would be the start of a week. And the previous week would be 11-17 November. And the week before would be 3-10 November etc. How can I create these dates and then aggregate these together for example the 11-17 November with 3-10 November for the table?

Comment: [How to select SQL results grouped by weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6410134/102937)

Comment: this question was asked lots of times and there are valid answers, you have to do more thorough search. if you don't find the answer I will look myself tomorrow and post the link here

Comment: https://chartio.com/learn/amazon-redshift/how-to-generate-series/